# For a given hash value, is it possible to guess whether it is generated by MD5 or SHA-1?

Tags: hash-function

Given a hash value, is it possible to guess the hash function used to generate it?
For example, let's say that `9b35a8503abcecadfb85726cfefb99a9` is generated by MD5 or SHA-1(If it's SHA-1, let's say that it is only the first 16 bytes of it), and the content was plain english text. Is there any hint that makes it more likely to be generated by MD5 than SHA-1 or vice versa?

Comment: If both MD5 and SHA1 output a vector of independent pseudorandom bits with the same distribution, then they must be indistinguishable. IIRC, this is the case. You might get a better answer at [security.SE](//security.stackexchange.com), though.

Answer (score 0):

No. If there was, that would indicate some defect in the hashing algorithm.

Of course, you can search against a rainbow table or by brute force. But other than that, there's no significant hint.